# sequence of tenses in quoting others

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Ryan et al. (2005) added that in-depth assessment of the family was important, and this could be best achieved by considering all points of view and by exploring a broad range of family functions, including how they had been communicating, solving problems, allocating roles and responsibilities, engaging emotionally with each other, and setting rules and expectations (as cited in Keitner, 2005).

or

Ryan et al. (2005) added that in-depth assessment of the family is important, and this is best achieved by considering all points of view and by exploring a broad range of family functions, including how they communicate, solve problems, allocate roles and responsibilities, engage emotionally with each other, and set rules and expectations (as cited in Keitner, 2005).

Comment: There are other possibilities. One of which I'd use.

Comment: The question is: do I need to use the past tense after “added” or I can continue with present despite of “added” was used in the beginning of the sentence

Comment: "Ryan et al. (2005) added that in-depth assessment of the family is important" is perfectly acceptable, and in fact to be preferred, where the facts are still as stated (ie in-depth assessment of the family is still important in 2018, or in-depth assessment of the family is always important). This has been addressed here before.

Comment: One directly addressing quotes is [Should we use past tense here: "Lugo admitted that he is the father"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/should-we-use-past-tense-in-lugo-admitted-he-is-the-father).